# What does runaway failure mean (position difference between APPU and FPPU) on A320?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a320, control-surfaces

I've been reading the description and operation of Flap systems. WTBs will stop and hold the transmission whenever SFCCs receive some failures.

Answer (score 3):

A runaway failure of an actuator is a situation where the actuator deflects maximally into one of its stops and stays there. Particularly hydraulic actuators can be subject to these: if the servo valve cannot close due to for instance dirt being stuck in the valve, oil flow will cause this type of failure. Electrical actuators commanded by a servo loop can fail in this mode as well.